# OData WebService (java) giving Error Result - Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013-sp1, java, odata

OData Webservice base url http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc hit on browser working fine; results below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://dvlapp52:11090/cd_webservice/odata.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="BinaryVariants">
            <atom:title>BinaryVariants</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="StructureGroups">
            <atom:title>StructureGroups</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Pages">
            <atom:title>Pages</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Binaries">
            <atom:title>Binaries</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Components">
            <atom:title>Components</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Templates">
            <atom:title>Templates</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Publications">
            <atom:title>Publications</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="ComponentPresentations">
            <atom:title>ComponentPresentations</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="CustomMetas">
            <atom:title>CustomMetas</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Schemas">
            <atom:title>Schemas</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="BinaryContents">
            <atom:title>BinaryContents</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="PageContents">
            <atom:title>PageContents</atom:title>
        </collection>
        <collection href="Keywords">
            <atom:title>Keywords</atom:title>
        </collection>
    </workspace>
</service>
```

Odata webservice base url when hit with any collection it gives same error result on the browser:
http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations
http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc/Components
http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc/Pages

**OUTPUT (error result on browser):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <code></code>
    <message xml:lang="en-US">Unable to build publication entry: No resource was found for the requested item</message>
```

**OData webservice logs below:**

```
2017-04-27 16:38:24,860 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: SpringLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:24,860 INFO  SpringConfigurationLoader - Starting loading spring application context
2017-04-27 16:38:25,403 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryBeanConfigurer - Attempt loading hibernate configuration file.
2017-04-27 16:38:25,405 DEBUG JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer - Registering compat JDBC data source
2017-04-27 16:38:25,409 DEBUG PooledDataSourceBeanConfigurer - Initializing Pooled data source
2017-04-27 16:38:25,417 DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryBeanConfigurer - Registering EntityManagerFactory to Spring Context
2017-04-27 16:38:25,526 INFO  SpringConfigurationLoader - Finished loading spring application context
2017-04-27 16:38:25,526 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: BundleLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:25,532 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: FactoryLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:27,210 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded BinaryDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,224 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded BinaryMetaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,228 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded BinaryVariantDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,233 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ComponentLinkClickDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,233 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ComponentMetaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,238 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ComponentPresentationDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,242 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ComponentPresentationMetaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,246 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ComponentVisitDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,251 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded DynamicLinkInfoDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,252 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ItemMetaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,256 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded LinkInfoDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,260 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded PageDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,260 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded PageMetaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,265 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded PersonalizationDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,270 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded PublicationMappingDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,274 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded PublicationDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,279 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded ReferenceDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,287 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded QueryDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,291 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded SchemaDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,297 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded TaxonomyDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,301 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded TimeframeDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,305 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded TrackedPageDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,309 DEBUG JPADAOFactory - Loaded XSLTDAO for storageId: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,328 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: TypeMappingCheckLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:27,330 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: ConfigurationItemTypeLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:27,331 INFO  ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded default storage: defaultdb
2017-04-27 16:38:27,331 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loading default global typeMappings
2017-04-27 16:38:27,331 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loaded mapping: binary to storage: defaultFile
2017-04-27 16:38:27,331 DEBUG ConfigurationItemTypeLoader - Loading publication storage mappings
2017-04-27 16:38:27,331 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: CacheLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:27,332 INFO  ConfigurationStepLoader - Executing configuration step: StorageWrapperLoader
2017-04-27 16:38:27,335 INFO  StorageManagerTransactionMonitor - Starting storage transaction monitoring
2017-04-27 16:38:27,336 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Default storage provider has caching set to: false
2017-04-27 16:38:27,336 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loaded following dao Properties[publication=0, typeMapping=Query, storageId=defaultdb, cached=false] for publication/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / Query / null
2017-04-27 16:38:27,336 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 0 / Query / null
2017-04-27 16:38:27,336 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Wrapping DAO's, currently 0 wrappers installed
2017-04-27 16:38:27,801 DEBUG ResolverBase - Chained error, returning original OData error response
2017-04-27 16:38:27,803 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
2017-04-27 16:38:39,613 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Rewrite url from: /cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc/PageContents
2017-04-27 16:38:39,613 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Getting publication url for: ws
2017-04-27 16:38:39,614 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Rewrite url to:   /odata.svc/Publications(1)/PageContents
2017-04-27 16:38:39,614 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Requested a OData feed/entry: Publications(1)/PageContents with type: application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8
2017-04-27 16:38:39,614 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Setting $top to 500
2017-04-27 16:38:39,615 DEBUG ResolverBase - Resolving a chained relation
2017-04-27 16:38:39,616 DEBUG ResolverBase - Requested specific OData Entry
2017-04-27 16:38:39,617 DEBUG ResolverBase - Chained error, returning original OData error response
2017-04-27 16:38:39,617 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
2017-04-27 22:29:29,043 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Rewrite url from: /cd_webservice/ws/odata.svc/Pages
2017-04-27 22:29:29,043 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Getting publication url for: ws
2017-04-27 22:29:29,043 DEBUG ODataPublicationMappingFilter - Rewrite url to:   /odata.svc/Publications(1)/Pages
2017-04-27 22:29:29,044 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Requested a OData feed/entry: Publications(1)/Pages with type: application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8
2017-04-27 22:29:29,044 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Setting $top to 500
2017-04-27 22:29:29,044 DEBUG ResolverBase - Resolving a chained relation
2017-04-27 22:29:29,044 DEBUG ResolverBase - Requested specific OData Entry
2017-04-27 22:29:29,089 DEBUG ResolverBase - Chained error, returning original OData error response
2017-04-27 22:29:29,089 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
```

I have not enabled Ambient data framework; seems its optional. below sdl documentation steps are followed for Odata web-service setup:

[Docs SDL com](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-9CEB3923-4CEE-41FA-87EE-712D7C555A91#docid=GUID-4B2B0768-7EB3-4518-9F95-2DD59FD2E287&filename=GUID-4B2B0768-7EB3-4518-9F95-2DD59FD2E287.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-4B2B0768-7EB3-4518-9F95-2DD59FD2E287)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue Solved:**
only change in the url.
Below are the correct complete urls that works as expected:

http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/odata.svc/ComponentPresentations
http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/odata.svc/Components
 http://myserver:11090/cd_webservice/odata.svc/Pages

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error logs

```
2017-04-27 16:38:27,801 DEBUG ResolverBase - Chained error, returning original OData error response
2017-04-27 16:38:27,803 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
```

There are still some references/configurations to Ambient Data Framework which is causing issues for you